# Does Dungeon Siege 2 on Steam come with Broken World?

Tags: steam, dungeon-siege-2

So ages ago I had the CDs of *Dungeon Siege 2* and after beating the game it didn't seem to conclude the plot. After looking it and *Dungeon Siege 3* up I learned that *Dungeon Siege 2* has an expansion which continues the plot called *Broken World*.

I noticed that *Dungeon Siege 2* is on [Steam](http://store.steampowered.com/app/39200/) under it's original name but mention of the Expansion isn't listed in it's description (like how some older games re-released get their expansions included with the game like with [Age of Empires 2](http://store.steampowered.com/app/221380/) coming with The Conquerors) nor does it appear as separate DLC.

The only reason why I would re-buy this game through Steam which I already have on disk is to get *Broken World*. So does *Dungeon Siege 2* on Steam come with *Broken World*?

Comment: Most of the [negative reviews of the Steam version](http://steamcommunity.com/app/39200/negativereviews/?browsefilter=toprated&snr=1_5_reviews_#scrollTop=700) point to the lack to two things: the *Broken World* expansion, and any kind of multiplayer.

Answer (score 1):

This may not fully qualify as an answer, but Steam user Valkyrie made a guide about how to get *Broken World* to work with the *DS2* Steam edition. Here is the [link](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=1165078098).

> ##### To make the expansion work with Steam, you'll need few missing files.
>
> [Download Link](https://pastebin.com/Gcg9qLLp)
>
> - On the download link look on the right corner of the screen and select download everything as a zip file.
> - After downloading open the Dungeon Siege II (Broken World) Fix.
> - Copy everything inside that folder to your Dungeon Siege installation folder.
> - Copy the reg-patch to your installation folder.
> - Install the registry fix as Administrator by right-clicking on the fix and then click Run as Administrator.
>
> This register fix makes your computer aware of where the game in installed, it is required to run the game and also needed for mod managers and some tools.
>
> Installing this will not only give you access to Broken World and multiplayer but it will also update your game to the lastest version and run with some few custom compability patches to fix some bugs such as sound/graphic/mouse input lags.

It contains a link to a download of *Broken World* which also contains a registry patch. I have not tested it, but by the sheer number of awards on the guide, I guess it works.